# Use coordinates of bounding box

Tags: tikz-pgf, coordinates, scoping

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{latexcolors}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{scope}[local bounding box = bbox]
        \draw[fill=blizzardblue] (-2,0) rectangle (2,0.3);
        \draw[fill=dimgray] (-1.5,0.3) rectangle (1.5,0.7);
        \draw[fill=blizzardblue] (-2,0.7) rectangle (2,1);
        \draw[pattern=north east lines, pattern color=coral, draw=coral] (-2.2,1) rectangle (2.2,1.5);
        \draw[fill=peach] (-2.3,0) -- (-2.3,2) -- (2.3,2) -- (2.3,0) -- (2.5,0) -- (2.5,2.2) -- (-2.5,2.2) -- (-2.5,0) -- cycle;
    \end{scope}

    \begin{scope}[x={(a.south east)},y={(a.north west)}]
    \draw (0,0) -- (1,1);
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

First, a scope is created and some drawing is made in that scope. Also, I assign the scope a bounding box name (`bbox`).

Later, I create a second scope, and I want that scope's coordinate `(0,0)` to correspond with `(bbox.south west)`, while `(1,1)` shall map to `(bbox.north east)`.

The result which I expect is the following:

[image: expected result]

However, the result I actually get looks like this:

[image: actual result]

a) why is this so? for `tikz-imagelabels` I did it exactly like this, and there it works, why doesn't it work with a scope? see [here](https://github.com/tcpluess/tikz-imagelabels/blob/master/tikz-imagelabels.dtx), line 543.
b) how can I fix that?

Comment: The points (0,0) and (1,1) use the same coordinate as before.  This isn't like (rel axis cs: x,y) from pgfplots.  OTOH, see page 140 of the PGF manual.

Answer (score 2):

In your code, you define the `x` and `y` directions/lengths in the second scope using whole coordinates, not scalar lengths. `(0,0)` stays at the origin as you don't shift the scope, `(1,1)` is some weird combination of the coordinates of the two corners of the first bounding box. What you need to do is shifting your scope to `bbox.south west` and adjusting the `x` and `y` lengths using scalar values, i.e., the width and height of `bbox`.

You can use `\pgfgetlastxy` to extract the coordinates of a node. Using these, the following code should do the trick:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{scope}[local bounding box=bbox]
        \draw[fill=cyan!30!white] (-2,0) rectangle (2,0.3);
        \draw[fill=red!30!white] (0,-1) rectangle (0.3,0.7);
    \end{scope}

    \path (bbox.south west);
    \pgfgetlastxy{\XA}{\YA};

    \path (bbox.north east);
    \pgfgetlastxy{\XB}{\YB};

    \begin{scope}[x=\XB-\XA, y=\YB-\YA, xshift=\XA, yshift=\YA]
    \draw[red] (0,0) -- (1,1);
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1. If you load the `calc` library, you could also do `\begin{scope}[shift={(bbox.south west)},x={($(bbox.south east)-(bbox.south
 west)$)},y={($(bbox.north west)-(bbox.south west)$)}]`

Answer (score 1):

Is there special reason, that you looking for so complicated way to draw your image? If not, you can simplify your document example to:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{latexcolors}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{scope}[local bounding box=f]
\draw[fill=blizzardblue]    (-2,0)      rectangle (2,0.3);
\draw[fill=dimgray]         (-1.5,0.3)  rectangle (1.5,0.7);
\draw[fill=blizzardblue]    (-2,0.7)    rectangle (2,1);
\draw[pattern=north east lines,
      pattern color=coral, 
      draw=coral]           (-2.2,1)    rectangle (2.2,1.5);
\draw[fill=peach] (-2.3,0) |- (2.3,2) |- (2.5,0) |- (-2.5,2.2) |- cycle;
    \end{scope}
\coordinate (a) at (f.south west);
\coordinate (b) at (f.north east);
\draw[red] (a) -- (b);
% or
%\draw[red] (f.south west) -- (f.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]